# Using Application Insights from multiple regions

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights

I'm trying to find any documentation/advisory info on whether or not to use the same App Insights instance from multiple regions. I'm assuming that if I have an API App Service in useast, it's not recommended to use an App Insights instance from West region as it would add latency.

Answer (score 4):

I just got the feedback from MS application insights team, the answer is no performance issue:

> Application insights sends data to their backend asynchronously - so
> the actual network RT time should not matter.
>
> Also, even though the
> app insights is in West Region, the 'ingest' endpoints are globally
> distributed, and telemetry is always sent to the nearest available
> 'ingest' point.

Details are [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/ApplicationInsights-Home/issues/299).

For the official document, I'm asking for it(but not sure if they would have one).

Hope it helps.